# Structure member alignment in GCC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, alignment

I'm porting an msvc project, which has several libraries and each library has specific structures member alignment. Using default alignment caused lots of fatal misalign problems and googling told me that I can solve this issue by setting alignment for each struct / class / union manually with the `__attribute__ ((aligned (MY_ALIGN)))` flag, however there is one thing that bothers me:

Let's say for simplicity sake that project A uses 1 byte alignment and project B, which actively uses project A's functionality and includes lots of its headers, has 16 bytes alignment. Would there be a problem with that, or am I thinkg too much and it would just work? I have a bad feeling that when building a library, msvc compiler sets alignment for each structs in all headers (no matter if they are included in a project or are referenced by sources). Is this true? And if it is, please tell me, how should I set the alignment to emulate MSVC's structure member alignment setting?

Comment: Unless you're using SIMD types (SSE), you really shouldn't get any problems if you use default alignment. If you do get errors, it's because you're doing soemthing horrible in your code which should be fixed.

Comment: Well, SSE extensions are being used extensively and there is a lot of code, which requires specific alignment...

Comment: Given SSE, you should be able to configure the compiler to output MOVUPS and alike, instead of MOVAPS. That "solves" your problem in the now-portable way. A second option would be to use a library that fixes alignment at 16 bytes, a third would be to create/integrate such a library from your project. Regardless, you should fix the alignment of structures and members inside the headers, not in project settings or compiler flags.

Comment: my point is that "normal" types are allocated correctly by the compiler, unless you explicitly break it (by performing dangerous casts which rely on undefined behavior). So if you get alignment errors *outside* of the SSE stuff, it might point to a deeper problem with your code

Comment: Dascandy, can you please tell me, how should I configure Apple GCC 4.2.1 compiler?

Comment: don't use -fpack-struct at all, let the compiler define how to align things. For SSE types, I'm not sure GCC even generates any SSE moves. If you use an SSE library it should take care of alignment with __attribute__((aligned(16))) or similar. For alignment, you can assume that any bit of data that starts on its natural alignment will not be padded by any compiler. For performance-oriented systems this is still true but only for types larger than or equal to its base type (int). So, doubles are always 8-byte aligned and won't get padding if they are, but two char[3]'s may get a byte of padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there should be an issue with that. Just remeber that unaligned access (4 byte minimum I think on most systems) will cost you (although you save space albeit not much in some situations). The structures themselves have the attribute and the compiler will do all the pointer arithmetic so as long as the headers don't mess with each other's definitions it should be okay.

Comment: it may depend on the architecture you compile for. Some CPUs don't allow unaligned access to certain types of variables (e.g. even addresses for int access needed, addresses for double need to be dividable by 8, ...). Other than that I don't see any problems as long as the alignment is used for the structs that need it and not globally turned on.

Comment: Yeah that was my point (unaligned access isn't a big deal). As long as the alignment isn't being overridden somewhere it's fine. Personally I don't bother with it as the compiler knows best.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but the project is being ported to the Mac OS X platform, where misalign causes application failure, so unaligned access is actually a very big problem...

Comment: That's fine you can keep your alignment that works as long as the headers don't clash with each other.

Comment: Thanks, Jesus! :) Can you please tell me, what do you mean by headers clash? Project A's headers are included in project B's sources and the entities defined in them are extensively used in project B...

Comment: By clash I mean if I define struct myStruct1 with alignment of 1 and then in header B i redefine the alignment to 4 that might cause issues but I find this highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, every header `#include`'d in your source file gets processes literally, it doesn't matter whether it in the same project or not.

It can definitely lead to some problems. For example, Project A defines a structure and aligns all its members to a byte boundary (packed) and exports a function accepting a pointer to this structure.
Then if Project B for some reason is compiled in such an environment that the same structure gets aligned in a different way, it would make it impossible to pass an address of an instance of this `struct` directly to that exported routine. They have different `sizeof`s at least in A and B.

The simple rule is this:
1) if you're to be interfacing with some external compiled library, you should make sure that structure alignment is in agreement with that used by the library compiler. This concerns the structures present in library's headers. Good libraries try to minimize the effort by providing `#pragma`'s for some compilers to ensure the proper alignment.
2) if you're using structures inside some project of yours you can leave it alone, just write portable code that doesn't rely upon some specific alignment, it will do.